# How can i select the following text from the span using Selenium[Python]?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Following is the structure:**

```
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center marginTopMini infoMessage showInfo" ng-class="{ showInfo : servicesCtrl.texts.addressInfo != '' &amp;&amp; servicesCtrl.show.receipt === false }">
  <div class="infoMessageInner">
    <p>
      <span ng-bind-html="servicesCtrl.texts.addressInfo" class="ng-binding">
        Tyvärr kan vi inte erbjuda fiber eller tjänster på denna adress just nu. Vänligen kontrollera att adressen är rättstavad och enligt formatet <b>”Exempelgatan 17A, Ort”</b>.
        <br><br>Vi vill ge alla möjlighet till fiberanslutning. Gör en intresseanmälan för din adress så ökar chansen att vi kommer kunna erbjuda fiber även i ditt område.
      </span>
      <span ng-show="servicesCtrl.address.status === 'Orderable'" class="ng-hide"> 
        <a ng-click="servicesCtrl.preScrollToVerticalPosition('checkout', 'checkout', '/checkoutFiber', undefined, 'Checkout fiber')">
          Till&nbsp;fiberbeställningen</a>
        </span>
        <span ng-show="servicesCtrl.address.status === 'Inquireable'" class=""> 
          <a ng-click="servicesCtrl.preScrollToVerticalPosition('checkout', 'checkout', '/inquiry', undefined, 'Inquiry')">Till&nbsp;intresseanmälan</a>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can i select the following paragraph text using selenium**[Python]**. I've tried this method please have a look(doing using python):

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".showInfo.infoMessageInner")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.showInfo.infoMessageInner')))
data = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".showInfo.infoMessageInner")
```

Please suggest me valid solution that how can i retrieve the following text which is in the above paragraph tag(p). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. You just need to identify the `<p>` tag and induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be visible* and finally use `text` to retrieve the text as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#other lines of code
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.infoMessageInner > p")))
print(element.text)
```

The text extracted will be:

```
Tyvärr kan vi inte erbjuda fiber eller tjänster på denna adress just nu. Vänligen kontrollera att adressen är rättstavad och enligt formatet ”Exempelgatan 17A, Ort”.
        Vi vill ge alla möjlighet till fiberanslutning. Gör en intresseanmälan för din adress så ökar chansen att vi kommer kunna erbjuda fiber även i ditt område.



          Till fiberbeställningen


          Till intresseanmälan
```

Answer (score 1):

Your locator was just a bit off...

```
data = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.infoMessageInner > p')))
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to drill down more and then get the text or innerHTML, something like:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[@class='infoMessageInner'] span.ng-binding")).get_text()
```

I didn't verify this code but it should put you on the path.